# MYSQL group_concat with and IF

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Have a date field that I am getting out of my DB with the following;
PS Here is more of the query using a join to get the dates from the date table.

```
SELECT event,event_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(ed.date,'%b %e') ORDER BY ed.date SEPARATOR ',') as date2 
FROM events ev
LEFT JOIN event_dates ed ON ev.eid=ed.eid
WHERE ev.yr='2013' 
GROUP BY ev.eid
```

This produces this list of dates that takes up way to much space.

```
May 16,May 23,May 30,Jun 6,Jun 20
```

I want it to look like

```
   May 16,23,30,Jun 6,20
```

Here is the query I tried.  but it doesn't work because the sub-query doesn't seem to know the event id.   guessing i might need to convert it to a join??

```
SELECT DISTINCT ev.event_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(race_date,'%a') ORDER BY race_date 
SEPARATOR ',   ')   as date1,

(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(dm) FROM
 (SELECT CONCAT(
    MONTHNAME(race_date),
    ' ',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DAY(race_date) ORDER BY race_date)
    ) as dm 
FROM event_dates ed1 WHERE ed1.event_id=ev.event_id  
GROUP BY MONTH(race_date))as t) as date2

FROM events ev
JOIN event_dates ed ON ev.event_id = ed.event_id AND ev.race_year = ed.race_year 
GROUP BY event_id
```

Comment: What does `IF` have to do with your query ;) ?

Comment: @bonCodigo: Presumably, *if the month has already been included...*

Comment: @eggyal hmm... :) `group by Month(date)` does remove duplicates...

Comment: Yes the if I mentioned was one thought I had changing the dateformat chosen based on some condition like the first date of the month.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(d) FROM (
  SELECT    CONCAT(
              MONTHNAME(date),
              ' ',
              GROUP_CONCAT(DAY(date) ORDER BY date)
            ) AS d
  FROM      my_table
  GROUP BY  MONTH(date)
) t
```

Comment: Interesting,  I added more of my query to the original post but I see how this could work.

Comment: No luck with this yet  see the code I tried in my original post.

Comment: @davewhirlwind: Is every date for a given event guaranteed to occur on the same weekday?

Comment: No  some Fri, Sat, Sun  Some are one day only some are once a week same day.

Comment: @davewhirlwind: So how should the output to express this?

Comment: You can see the date formats I am looking for at http://www.regattaman.com/calendar.php this formatting is done in a php function call after the query,  was hoping to get it in the query to clean up the code.